# Custom formatter for a multi-valued field

Tags: 7, tokens, entities

I have a multi-valued image field and I'd like to use its delta value with the Custom Formatters module. What I want to do would be really simple with html+tokens if it were to work:

```
<div id="cf">
  <a href="[node:url]"><img class="bottom"  style="border:0;"src="[node:field_image:0]" alt="[node:title]" ></a>
  <a href="[node:url]"><img class="top"  style="border:0;" src="[node:field_image:1]" alt="[node:title]" ></a>
</div>
```

However, I don't see the option for the delta value available in the list of tokens available, and using that code would just end up with `[node:field_image:0]` and `[node:field_image:1]` being replaced as `src=""`

Could you please advice me on how to do this? I think I need to use php but I don't know how. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

here a sample for rendering (image) fields but you can easily access to other fields of entity:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($variables['#items'] as $item) {
  $output .= theme('file_link', array('file' => (object) $item));
}
return $output;
```

Another line example for manual image rendering:

```
$output .= '<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="'.image_style_url('YOUR_IMAGE_STYLE', $your_entity->your_field['und'][0]['uri']).'" alt="'.$your_entity->your_field['und'][0]['alt'].'"/>';
```