# How to create a single slideshow combining several image fields?

Tags: 7, media, views

I have 3 image fields in a content type: img1,img2 and img3. img3 is multi valued while the rest are single valued, and I'd like to create a single slideshow containing img1, img2 and img3 to be showed on every node of that content type.

I tried using views slideshow with as block with contextual filters and managed to select images from a node correctly, but they weren't displayed properly as a slideshow.

The reason I'm not simply using one image field to make things easier is that I'm using the Custom Formatters module and I have problems with using just one field with that module:

[Custom formatter for a multi-valued field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133639/custom-formatter-for-a-multi-valued-field)

Comment: Check my related question about merging fields (before rendering): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135814/alter-field-multiple-values-to-add-more-items-values-of-another-field/135898#135898

Answer (score 1):

```
  <?php if ( ($image_slide == 'true') ): ?>
        <div class="image-post-slider">
              <ul>
                <?php while ($img_count < $counter) { ?>
                  <li>
                          <div class="preloader">
                                <a class="bwWrapper single-image link-icon" href="<?php print $node_url; ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][$img_count]['uri']); ?>" alt="" >
                                </a>                        
                            </div>
                  </li>
                  <?php $img_count++; } ?>      
              </ul>
        </div>    
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Put something like above snippet in your node.tpl.php
This will create links of images and their links if any. Then apply normal css/js to make it in slideshow

Comment: thanks, but I need a slideshow that combines several fields, not just one field.

Comment: Just loop through all images like this

`<?php
for($i=0; $i < count($node->field_image['und']); $i++){
<img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][$i]['uri']); ?>" alt="" >
}
for($j=0; $j < count($node->field_other_image['und']); $j++){
<img src="<?php echo file_create_url($node->field_other_image['und'][$j]['uri']); ?>" alt="" >
}
?>`

and follow @Shabir's advice for the css/js.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Jcarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel) module.

> This module allows developers and themers to make use of the jCarousel jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as Views integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.

Image from project page

[image]

If you want to add additional features have a look at [Views Slideshow JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel)

> Integrates JCarousel features into views slideshow version 6.x-3.x or 7.x. Currently provides a JCarousel pager widget.